# Pseudo Vandermonde fomula

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Given integers $m,n$ such that $1\le m\le n$,  let us consider the set $SI_{m,n}$ of all **s**trictly **i**ncreasing maps from $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

It is well known that $SI_{m,n}=\binom nm$.

Now let us choose $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$, $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and consider the maps $f\in SI_{m,n}$ which satisfy $f(i)=j$.

We see that :

- if $j<i$ or $j>n-m+i$, then there are no such maps
- if $i\le j\le n-m+i$, there are $\binom{j-1}{i-1}\binom{n-j}{m-i}$ such maps

Summing up, we get the nice formula :

$$\sum_{j=i}^{n-m+i}\binom{j-1}{i-1}\binom{n-j}{m-i}=\binom nm$$

Putting $p=i-1$, $q=j-1$ and re-indexing, we can rewrite it as follows :

> $$\sum_{j=p}^{n-q}\binom{j}{p}\binom{n-j}{q}=\binom{n+1}{p+q+1}$$

Wich looks pretty much like but IS NOT the well-known Vandermonde formula.

**Hence my question :** Does this formula has a standard name ? To whom is it commonly attributed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu.E2.80.93Vandermonde_identity)* 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{s}{j}\binom{t}{m-j}=\binom{s+t}{m}\qquad\qquad s,t\in\mathbb{C}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
is a generalisation of *Vandermonde's identity* for arguments not only integers but elements from $\mathbb{C}$.

> Here we show OPs identity is a *Chu-Vandermonde identity* in disguise. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=p}^{n-q}\binom{j}{p}\binom{n-j}{q}&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-p-q}\binom{j+p}{p}\binom{n-j-p}{q}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n-p-q}\binom{j+p}{j}\binom{n-p-j}{n-p-q-j}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n-p-q}\binom{-p-q}{j}\binom{-q-1}{n-p-q-j}(-1)^{n-p-q}\tag{4}\\
> &=(-1)^m\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{-p-1}{j}\binom{-q-1}{m-j}\tag{5}\\
> &=(-1)^m\binom{-p-q-2}{m}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we shift the index $j$ to start with $j=0$.
- In (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$.
- In (4) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k$.
- In (5) we use the substitution $m=n-p-q$.
- In (6) we apply the *Chu-Vandermonde identity* (1).

> We conclude from (5) and (6) OP's binomial identity is equivalent with the *Chu-Vandermonde identity*
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{-p-1}{j}\binom{-q-1}{m-j}=\binom{-p-q-2}{m}}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Identity 5.26 of [Concrete Mathematics](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/gkp.html) (Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik) is $$\sum_{0\le k\le l} \binom{l-k}{m} \binom{q+k}{n} = \binom{l+q+1}{m+n+1}$$ Under the substitutions $(k,l,m,n,q) \to (j,n,q,p,0)$ we get $$\sum_{0\le j\le n} \binom{j}{p} \binom{n-j}{q} = \binom{n+1}{p+q+1}$$ and this is the same as your sum because although the indices of the sum differ, in the range where they differ the summand is zero.

Now for the disappointment: this is Vandermonde in disguise. Exercise 5.14 is

> Prove identity (5.25) by negating the upper index in Vandermonde's convolution (5.22). Then show that another negation yields (5.26).

For completeness, their presentation of (5.22) is $$\sum_k \binom{r}{m+k} \binom{s}{n-k} = \binom{r+s}{m+n}$$ and (5.25) is $$\sum_{k \le l} \binom{l-k}{m} \binom{s}{k-n} (-1)^k = (-1)^{l+m} \binom{s-m-1}{l-m-n}$$

GKP give no name to the identity nor attribution for it, and since they're usually good with attribution I assume that none is known.

Comment: Thank you very much for this reference ! I agree with your final remark about naming :)